# 3x3 ANOVA dummy coded by hand

Tags: anova, categorical-data

What does a 3x3 ANOVA dummy code scheme look like with one observation per cell? I am showing it in a Word document and can't use a program to design it. I have found other examples of dummy coding but not for a 3x3 ANOVA and I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine these are the levels:

Factor 1: A, B, C

Factor 2: P, Q, R

For each level of each factor you set up an indicator variable (0-1 variable, dummy variable) that is "1" when that factor takes that level and "0" otherwise.

So for any observation that has level A of factor 1, you put a 1 in the column for its "A" indicator on factor 1.

The interactions are then the products of the corresponding main effects. For example the column for the interaction of level C of factor 1 and level R of factor 2 will have a 1 when the observation is both C and R.

There are only 9 combinations of factors, so all of your rows of IVs will look like one of the rows here (less some columns). After the first column of interactions I have suppressed the 0's (you have to put them in) so you can
see more clearly.

```
          |        Main effects                Interactions
Fac1 Fac2 | F1A F1B F1C  F2P F2Q F2R   A.P B.P C.P A.Q B.Q C.Q A.R B.R C.R
 A    P   |  1   0   0    1   0   0     1   
 B    P   |  0   1   0    1   0   0     0   1
 C    P   |  0   0   1    1   0   0     0       1
 A    Q   |  1   0   0    0   1   0     0           1
 B    Q   |  0   1   0    0   1   0     0               1  
 C    Q   |  0   0   1    0   1   0     0                   1
 A    R   |  1   0   0    0   0   1     0                       1
 B    R   |  0   1   0    0   0   1     0                           1
 C    R   |  0   0   1    0   0   1     0                               1
```

Note that you will leave out one of the factor levels from each factor, and you won't fit any of the interaction terms with that level. So for example, if you leave out A and P you will omit the columns labelled F1A and F2P as well as the
A.P, B.P, C.P, A.Q, A.R interactions... but you will include the constant term which has "1" for every row.